# If creating files from code that is exercised via Tests is disallowed, how can such methods be tested?

Tags: c#, file-io, outlook, filesystems, mstest

I'm trying to test a method from a Test project like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestEmailGeneratedReport()
{
    List<String> recipients = new List<string>();
    recipients.Add("bclayshannon@hotmail.net");
    recipients.Add("axx3andspace@male.edu");
    recipients.Add("cshannon@PlatypiRUs.com");
    bool succeeded = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.EmailGeneratedReport(recipients);
    Assert.IsTrue(succeeded);
}
```

...but it blows up; I get, "*Could not find a part of the path.*"

It works fine, though, when I call it like this from the project's main form's Load event:

```
List<String> recipients = new List<string>();
recipients.Add("bclayshannon@hotmail.net");
recipients.Add("axx3andspace@male.edu");
recipients.Add("cshannon@PlatypiRUs.com");
bool succeeded = 
    RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.EmailGeneratedReport(recipients);
if (succeeded) MessageBox.Show("emailing succeeded");
```

...I see the "emailing succeeded" message.

The method under test conditionally creates a folder:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueFolder))
{
    uniqueFolder = GetUniqueFolder("Test");
    ConditionallyCreateDirectory(uniqueFolder);
}
```

So virtually the same code works in the real project, but fails from the Test project; I assume the crux of the problem is the creation of the folder. Are tests, or "remote" code disallowed from manipulating the file system in this way, is that what's happening here? If so, how can a method that does such things be tested?

### UPDATE

Note: I *am* able to read from the file system; this test succeeds:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetLastReportsGenerated()
{
    string testFolderThatHasExcelFiles = "C:\\Misc";
    FileInfo[] aBunchOfFiles = 
        RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.GetLastReportsGenerated(
            testFolderThatHasExcelFiles);
    Assert.IsTrue(aBunchOfFiles.Length > 0);
}
```

### UPDATE 2

And I'm able to manipulate files, too:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMarkFileAsSent()
{
    string fileToRename = "C:\\Misc\\csharpExcelTest.xlsx";
    string desiredRenamedFileName = "C:\\Misc\\csharpExcelTest_PROCESSED.xlsx";
    RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.MarkFileAsSent(fileToRename);
    bool oldFileNameExists = System.IO.File.Exists(fileToRename);
    bool newFileNameExists = System.IO.File.Exists(desiredRenamedFileName);
    Assert.IsTrue((newFileNameExists) && (!oldFileNameExists));
}
```

...so...?!?

### UPDATE 3

I temporarily commmented out the folder creation code, and it still breaks, so it wasn't that...maybe Testing and Outlook Interop don't mix?

### UPDATE 4

For Arturo:

```
internal static bool EmailGeneratedReport(List<string> recipients)
{
    bool success = true;
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        Recipients _recipients = mailItem.Recipients;
        foreach (string recip in recipients)
        {
            Recipient outlookRecipient = _recipients.Add(recip);
            outlookRecipient.Type = (int)OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
            outlookRecipient.Resolve();
        }
        mailItem.Subject = String.Format("Platypus Reports generated {0}", GetYYYYMMDDHHMM());

        List<String> htmlBody = new List<string>
        {
            "<html><body><img src=\"http://www.platypiRUs.com/wp-content/themes/platypi/images/pru_logo_notag.png\" alt=\"Platypus logo\" ><p>Your Platypus reports are attached. You can also view them online here:</p>"
        };
        htmlBody.Add("</body></html>");
        mailItem.HTMLBody = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, htmlBody.ToArray());

        // Commented this out to see if it was the problem with the test failing (it wasn't)
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueFolder))
        {
            uniqueFolder = GetUniqueFolder("Test");
            ConditionallyCreateDirectory(uniqueFolder);
        }

        FileInfo[] rptsToEmail = GetLastReportsGenerated(uniqueFolder);
        foreach (var file in rptsToEmail)
        {
            String fullFilename = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", uniqueFolder, file.Name);
            if (!File.Exists(fullFilename)) continue;
            if (!file.Name.Contains(PROCESSED_FILE_APPENDAGE))
            {
                mailItem.Attachments.Add(fullFilename);
            }
            MarkFileAsSent(fullFilename);
        }
        mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
        mailItem.Display(false);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        String exDetail = String.Format(ExceptionFormatString, ex.Message,
            Environment.NewLine, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
        MessageBox.Show(exDetail);
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

### UPDATE 5

More for Arturo:

```
// Provided the unit name, returns a folder name like "C:\\RoboReporter\\Gramps\\201602260807
internal static string GetUniqueFolder(string _unit)
{
    if (uniqueFolder.Equals(String.Empty))
    {
        uniqueFolder = String.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}", OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, _unit, GetYYYYMMDDHHMM());
    }
    return uniqueFolder;
}

internal static FileInfo[] GetLastReportsGenerated(string _uniqueFolder)
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(_uniqueFolder);
    return d.GetFiles(ALL_EXCEL_FILE_EXTENSION); 
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+exorcise No.

Comment: Nice jQuery Tut, BTW.

Comment: `RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.EmailGeneratedReport()` reads some data from config files or use a relative address of a email template?

Comment: No, I'll post the whole thing, though, just for the much-yearned-for "full disclosure"

Comment: If you comment `FileInfo[] rptsToEmail ...` and `foreach loop` the exception is still thrown?

Comment: No, commenting that out, the test runs fine; but why would that be an issue? GetLastReportsGenerated() works fine when tested; so does MarkFileAsSent()

Comment: probably `uniqueFolder` is a relative path but cannot be sure without `GetUniqueFolder()` or `GetLastReportsGenerated()` code. Try debugging the test to see what is the value of `uniqueFolder`.

Comment: I going to add an answer with some code. may works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do better checks about reports folder.

Try replacing:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueFolder))
{
    uniqueFolder = GetUniqueFolder("Test");
    ConditionallyCreateDirectory(uniqueFolder);
}
```

with:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueFolder))
    uniqueFolder = GetUniqueFolder("Test");

if (!Directory.Exists(uniqueFolder))
    ConditionallyCreateDirectory(uniqueFolder);
```

Also, you should use `Path` class to work with paths:

```
String fullFilename = Path.Combine(uniqueFolder, file.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks; I'll try it, but why would it work "raw" (directly from the app). I'll check it...

Comment: Maybe OUTPUT_DIRECTORY is a relative address or uniqueFolder takes values from other method in normal run.

Comment: No, OUTPUT_DIRECTORY is just a normal constant, namely:
public static readonly string OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = "C:\\RoboReporter";
But it works now, so thankulations!