# How can I restrict the creation of subfolders and files to one location only?

Tags: c#, file, dynamic, network-programming, streaming

My app generates spreadsheet files and subfolders in which to categorize them, and then stores them in a shared folder on the network; it works fine - this network location exists:

```
\\storageblade\cs\REPORTING\RoboReporter
```

...and the app dynamically adds, as necessary, subfolders to that, such as:

```
\\storageblade\cs\REPORTING\RoboReporter\ABUELOS
```

...which in turn, get their own subfolders, such as:

```
\\storageblade\cs\REPORTING\RoboReporter\ABUELOS\20161230_1336
```

...which final subfolders contain the generated spreadsheet file[s].

I am saving the dynamically created subfolders and .xlsx files like so:

```
String _uniqueFolder = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.uniqueFolder;
var fromDate = _delPerfBeginDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
var toDate = _delPerfEndDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
var sharedFolder = String.Format(@"\\storageblade\cs\REPORTING\RoboReporter\{0}", _uniqueFolder);
RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.ConditionallyCreateDirectory(sharedFolder);
var filename = String.Format("{0}\\{1} - Delivery Performance - from {2} to {3}.xlsx", sharedFolder,
    _unit, fromDate, toDate);

if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    File.Delete(filename);
}
Stream stream = File.Create(filename);
package.SaveAs(stream);
stream.Close();
package.Save();
```

As I said, it's working fine - the folders and files are created in the shared network location.

*However*, the subfolders are also being created in the folder where the .exe lives. For example, on the dev machine, these end up in C:\Projects\~\bin\Debug, so that I have many subfolders such as:

```
C:\Projects\~\bin\Debug\ABUELOS\20161230_0908
```

...and on the "live" machine in the folder where I placed the .exe (as well as on the shared network area where they belong).

Here is the mysterious ConditionallyCreateDirectory() method:

```
internal static void ConditionallyCreateDirectory(string dirName)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
}
```

Why? And more importantly, how can I prevent this? I don't need this doubling up of file storage - some of these files are large, and will eventually cause the machine to fail, which will cause the network to fail, which will cause the business to fail, which will cause myself to be invited away from the premises, etc.

### UPDATE

In answer to OfirW's comment/question, here are, I think, the pertinent parts:

In RoboReporterConstsAndUtils:

```
public static string uniqueFolder = String.Empty;
. . .
internal static string GetUniqueFolder(string _unit)
{
    return uniqueFolder = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", _unit.ToUpper(), GetYYYYMMDDHHMM());
}

internal static void ConditionallyCreateDirectory(string dirName)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
}
```

How it is referenced elsewhere:

```
RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.ConditionallyCreateDirectory(RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.GetUniqueFolder(_unit));
                String _uniqueFolder = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.uniqueFolder;
```

_unit is assigned in the constructor:

```
public PriceComplianceRpt_EPPlus(DateTime begin, DateTime end, String unit)
{
    _begDate = begin;
    _endDate = end;
    _unit = unit;
}
```

...which is called like so:

```
internal static void GenerateAndSavePriceComplianceReport(QueuedReports qr)
{
    var pcr = new PriceComplianceRpt_EPPlus(qr.StartDateRange, qr.EndDateRange, qr.Unit);
    pcr.GeneratePriceComplianceRpt();
}
```

Comment: It's a fair bet that the problem is in RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.ConditionallyCreateDirectory, which you don't list

Comment: I added it; it probably shouldn't even be a separate method, it's so simple.

Comment: Also, you call package.SaveAs() as well as package.Save(); that might explain why it is written twice...

Comment: But why would it be in two different places?

Comment: package.SaveAs() writes to a stream you give it, which is probably when it gets written to the "right" place.  Who knows where package.Save() writes it; that might be where it gets written in the "wrong" place

Comment: Nope; that's not it - I commented out the .Save(); and tested, and the superfluous folders will still created in my bin\debug folder.

Comment: This is a long shot, `RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.uniqueFolder` is a static, are you setting this anywhere else in your code, change it to `const` to prove it. I found [some of your code here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660887/if-creating-files-from-code-that-is-exercised-via-tests-is-disallowed-how-can-s) again `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` might be static and being set by anything in the rest of the code base.

Comment: Yes, it is set to "<Unit>\<YYYYMMDD_HHMM>"; the problem being that this is saved also to where the .exe is running in addition to the designated location on the network. The only difference is, in the "unwanted" location, the *.xlsx files are not being stored, just the (empty) folders - well, the timestamp folder is empty; the "Unit" folder contains the timestamp folder, to be picky.

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.uniqueFolder - can you post it's value please on debug? Can you show us the code that generate the unique folder? maybe there you are creating the directory by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is where the additional directory is being created:

```
RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.ConditionallyCreateDirectory(RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.GetUniqueFolder(_unit));
```

why do you do that? 
I think you can change the class like this
In RoboReporterConstsAndUtils:

```
public static string uniqueFolder = String.Empty;
. . .
internal static void SetUniqueFolder(string _unit)
{
    uniqueFolder = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", _unit.ToUpper(), GetYYYYMMDDHHMM());
}

internal static void ConditionallyCreateDirectory(string dirName)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
}
```

and replace this:

```
RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.ConditionallyCreateDirectory(RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.GetUniqueFolder(_unit));
String _uniqueFolder = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.uniqueFolder;
```

With this:

```
RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.SetUniqueFolder(_unit));
String _uniqueFolder = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.uniqueFolder;
```

That's it it think